# Lucene Index with file system

Tags: lucene

I have created a Lucene indexer which will periodically look into a file system folder to read the   content of latest files to update the lucene catalog.

Problem arise, If we delete any file from above folder then above Indexer doesn't understand which file gets deleted so the same could be remove from catalog.

Can any one please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you implemented the polling on file system, but [here's how](http://java.dzone.com/news/how-watch-file-system-changes) delete events (among others) can be captured.